# what's the differences of the from_pretrained and weight.data.copy in Pytorch.Embedding

Tags: pytorch, embedding, glove

recently , I use glove to initialize the weight of Embedding, I find out the differences of from_pretrained and weight.data.copy_ is that : from_pretrained = {weight.data.copy_() ; embedding.weight.requires_grad = False}
I want to know if what I said is correct?
and I got 10% less accurate with the glove than I did without the glove, but when I count the words that are not covered by glove, I find that only 10% of the words are not in glove.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import unicodedata, re, string
import nltk

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader

import seaborn as sns

sns.set(color_codes=True)

df_train = pd.read_csv(r'E:\Mice\train.tsv', delimiter='\t')  # r代表反转义
df_test = pd.read_csv(r'E:\Mice\test.tsv', delimiter='\t')


def remove_non_ascii(words):
    """Remove non-ASCII characters from list of tokenized words"""
    new_words = []
    for word in words:
        new_word = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', word).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
        new_words.append(new_word)
    return new_words


def to_lowercase(words):
    """Convert all characters to lowercase from list of tokenized words"""
    new_words = []
    for word in words:
        new_word = word.lower()
        new_words.append(new_word)
    return new_words


def remove_punctuation(words):
    """Remove punctuation from list of tokenized words"""
    new_words = []
    for word in words:
        new_word = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', word)
        if new_word != '':
            new_words.append(new_word)
    return new_words


def remove_numbers(words):
    """Remove all interger occurrences in list of tokenized words with textual representation"""
    new_words = []
    for word in words:
        new_word = re.sub(r"\d+", "", word)
        if new_word != '':
            new_words.append(new_word)
    return new_words


def normalize(words):
    words = remove_non_ascii(words)
    words = to_lowercase(words)
    words = remove_punctuation(words)
    words = remove_numbers(words)
    #    words = remove_stopwords(words)
    return words


df_train['Words'] = df_train['Phrase'].apply(nltk.word_tokenize)
df_train['Words'] = df_train['Words'].apply(normalize)
word_set = set()
for l in df_train['Words']:
    for e in l:
        word_set.add(e)

# 从这里开始构建词向量，简单的索引。
word_to_int = {word: ii for ii, word in enumerate(word_set, 1)}
df_train['Tokens'] = df_train['Words'].apply(lambda l: [word_to_int[word] for word in l])
max_len = df_train['Tokens'].str.len().max()
all_tokens = np.array([t for t in df_train['Tokens']])
encoded_labels = np.array([l for l in df_train['Sentiment']])
features = np.zeros((len(all_tokens), max_len), dtype=int)
# for each phrase, add zeros at the end
for i, row in enumerate(all_tokens):
    features[i, :len(row)] = row
# 到这里词向量构建结束

# 下面是另一种, 用glove预训练。
embeddings_index = {}
f = open('E:/Mice/glove.6B.100d.txt', encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
    values = line.split()
    word = values[0]
    coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
    embeddings_index[word] = coefs
f.close()
# 同样属于glove, 构建词矩阵。
num = 0  # 计算下有多少数没有算进去。
tem_word = 0

embedding_matrix = np.zeros((len(word_to_int) + 1, 100))  # 因为预训练的glove就是100
for word, i in word_to_int.items():
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        # words not found in embedding index will be all-zeros.
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
    else:
        num = num + 1
        if num == 1:
            temp_word = i
# 要放在weight 中的。
print(embedding_matrix[tem_word])
print("未统计的数字：", num)
print("glove length", len(embeddings_index))
print("word length", len(word_to_int))

# split_frac = 0.8
# split_idx = int(len(features) * 0.8)
# train_x, remaining_x = features[:split_idx], features[split_idx:]
# train_y, remaining_y = encoded_labels[:split_idx], encoded_labels[split_idx:]
# test_idx = int(len(remaining_x) * 0.5)
# val_x, test_x = remaining_x[:test_idx], remaining_x[test_idx:]
# val_y, test_y = remaining_y[:test_idx], remaining_y[test_idx:]

split_frac = 0.8
split_idx = int(len(features) * 0.8)
train_x, remaining_x = features[:split_idx], features[split_idx:]
train_y, remaining_y = encoded_labels[:split_idx], encoded_labels[split_idx:]
test_idx = int(len(remaining_x) * 0.5)
val_x, test_x = remaining_x[:test_idx], remaining_x[test_idx:]
val_y, test_y = remaining_y[:test_idx], remaining_y[test_idx:]

train_data = TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(train_x), torch.from_numpy(train_y))
valid_data = TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(val_x), torch.from_numpy(val_y))
test_data = TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(test_x), torch.from_numpy(test_y))
batch_size = 54
# make sure the SHUFFLE your training data
train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)
valid_loader = DataLoader(valid_data, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_data, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)

train_on_gpu = torch.cuda.is_available()
if train_on_gpu:
    print('Training on GPU.')
else:
    print('No GPU available, training on CPU.')


class SentimentRNN(nn.Module):
    """
    The RNN model that will be used to perform Sentiment analysis.
    """

    def __init__(self, vocab_size, output_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, n_layers, drop_prob=0.5):
        """
        Initialize the model by setting up the layers.
        """
        super(SentimentRNN, self).__init__()

        self.output_size = output_size
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim

        # embedding and LSTM layers
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        self.embedding.weight.requires_grad = False
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim, hidden_dim, n_layers,
                            dropout=drop_prob, batch_first=True)

        # dropout layer
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.3)

        # linear
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_size)

    def forward(self, x, hidden):
        """
        Perform a forward pass of our model on some input and hidden state.
        """
        batch_size = x.size(0)  # input.shape = (54, 48)

        # embeddings and lstm_out
        x = x.long()  # 走的坑, 这里新增加了 .long()
        embeds = self.embedding(x)  # input 应该是： LongTensor of arbitrary shape containing the indices to extract
        # embeds.shape = (54, 48, 400)
        lstm_out, hidden = self.lstm(embeds, hidden)  # lstm_out.shape = (54, 48, 256)

        # transform lstm output to input size of linear layers
        lstm_out = lstm_out.transpose(0, 1)  # 48, 54, 256
        lstm_out = lstm_out[-1]  # lstm_out.shape = 54, 256

        out = self.dropout(lstm_out)
        out = self.fc(out)

        return out, hidden

    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        """ Initializes hidden state """
        # Create two new tensors with sizes n_layers x batch_size x hidden_dim,
        # initialized to zero, for hidden state and cell state of LSTM
        weight = next(self.parameters()).data  # 这里的shape是[16210, 400]  也是embedding的两个参数

        if train_on_gpu:
            hidden = (weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).zero_().cuda(),
                      weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).zero_().cuda())
            # new 和 view、reshape的区别于何处， zero_ 还是初始化成了 0
        else:
            hidden = (weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).zero_(),
                      weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).zero_())

        return hidden


# Instantiate the model w/ hyperparams
# vocab_size = len(word_to_int) + 1  # +1 for the 0 padding
vocab_size = len(word_set) + 1
output_size = 5
embedding_dim = 100
hidden_dim = 256
n_layers = 2

net = SentimentRNN(vocab_size, output_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, n_layers)
net.embedding.weight.data.copy_(torch.from_numpy(embedding_matrix))

lr = 0.003

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=lr)

# training params
epochs = 3  # 3-4 is approx where I noticed the validation loss stop decreasing

counter = 0
print_every = 100
clip = 5  # gradient clipping

# move model to GPU, if available
if train_on_gpu:
    net.cuda()

net.train()
# train for some number of epochs
for e in range(epochs):
    # initialize hidden state
    h = net.init_hidden(batch_size)

    # batch loop
    for inputs, labels in train_loader:
        # inputs.shape = (54, 48)    # batch_size 就是54 . 48是 token的长度  # labels.shpe = 54, 每一项都是分类.
        counter += 1

        if train_on_gpu:
            inputs, labels = inputs.cuda(), labels.cuda()

        # Creating new variables for the hidden state, otherwise
        # we'd backprop through the entire training history
        h = tuple([each.data for each in h])

        # zero accumulated gradients
        net.zero_grad()

        # get the output from the model
        output, h = net(inputs, h)  # output.shape = [54, 5]
        # calculate the loss and perform backprop
        loss = criterion(output.squeeze(), labels.long())  # 走的坑, 这里新增加了 .squeeze() ; .long()
        loss.backward()
        # `clip_grad_norm` helps prevent the exploding gradient problem in RNNs / LSTMs.
        nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(net.parameters(), clip)
        optimizer.step()

        # loss stats
        if counter % print_every == 0:
            # Get validation loss
            val_h = net.init_hidden(batch_size)
            val_losses = []
            net.eval()
            for inputs, labels in valid_loader:

                # Creating new variables for the hidden state, otherwise
                # we'd backprop through the entire training history
                val_h = tuple([each.data for each in val_h])

                if train_on_gpu:
                    inputs, labels = inputs.cuda(), labels.cuda()

                output, val_h = net(inputs, val_h)
                val_loss = criterion(output.squeeze(), labels.long())

                val_losses.append(val_loss.item())

            net.train()
            print("Epoch: {}/{}...".format(e + 1, epochs),
                  "Step: {}...".format(counter),
                  "Loss: {:.6f}...".format(loss.item()),
                  "Val Loss: {:.6f}".format(np.mean(val_losses)))

test_losses = []  # track loss
num_correct = 0
# init hidden state
h = net.init_hidden(batch_size)
net.eval()
# iterate over test data
for inputs, labels in test_loader:
    # Creating new variables for the hidden state, otherwise
    # we'd backprop through the entire training history
    h = tuple([each.data for each in h])

    if train_on_gpu:
        inputs, labels = inputs.cuda(), labels.cuda()

    # get predicted outputs
    output, h = net(inputs, h)
    # calculate loss
    test_loss = criterion(output.squeeze(), labels.long())
    test_losses.append(test_loss.item())

    # convert output probabilities to predicted class
    _, pred = torch.max(output, 1)

    # compare predictions to true label
    correct_tensor = pred.eq(labels.view_as(pred))
    correct = np.squeeze(correct_tensor.numpy()) if not train_on_gpu else np.squeeze(correct_tensor.cpu().numpy())
    num_correct += np.sum(correct)
    # -- stats! -- ##
    # avg test loss
    print("Test loss: {:.3f}".format(np.mean(test_losses)))
    # accuracy over all test data
test_acc = num_correct / len(test_loader.dataset)
print("Test accuracy: {:.3f}".format(test_acc))
print(net.embedding.weight[tem_word])
```

Comment: the dataset is [link](https://www.kaggle.com/c/sentiment-analysis-on-movie-reviews)  and glove is glove.6B.100d.txt